# Error "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'" on file upload

Tags: python, pylons

I'm using Pylons to upload an image and store it to disk:

```
 <form method="post">
 <input type="file" name="picture" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
 </form>
```

Then in my controller:

```
 if 'picture' in request.POST:

     i = ImageHandler()

     #Returns full path of image file
     picture_file = i.makePath()

     shutil.copyfileobj(request.POST['picture'],picture_file)
```

But I receive the error:
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'

What's going on here?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both arguments to `copyfileobj` are now strings, while that functions takes files (or "file-like objects") as arguments. Do something like

```
 picture_file = open(i.makePath(), 'w')
```

(or just `picture_file = i`, not sure what your `ImageHandler` class is like), then

```
 shutil.copyfileobj(request.POST['picture'].file, picture_file)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I still get the same error, though.  Could it be a problem with my first argument?  Or is request.POST['picture'] correct as is?

Comment: This is so strange, when I do that, I get:   AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'file'

Comment: The reason you are having trouble after following larsman's answer is that you are not actually uploading the file. This is because the `enctype` parameter in the HTML goes on the *form*, not the field.